# sqlalchemy OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database in a remote system.The relevant code is given below

```
log = core.getLogger()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////name:pass@192.168.129.139/tmp/nwtopology.db',echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String,index=True)

    #-----------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address
        self.port_no     = port_no
```

Obviously I am trying to create the database in a remote system. I am getting the error:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None
```

My questions are as follows.

1) the user that is running the program on local machine is not the same as the user that is trying to create the database on the remote machine.Is this an issue?

2) Are there any mechanisms to improve the latency of inserting an entry into the database and querying and entry by creating a local cached copy?

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [my answer with details explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443697/1296661) to [your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428891/remote-database-creation-in-sql-alchemy-via-sqlite).

Also here are some step by step guides how to install and configure remote database.
I would say try MySQL first - IMHO it is simpler that PosgreSQL.

- [How to install mysql on windows](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-mysql/)
- [How to install mysql on linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/howto-install-mysql-on-linux/)

Also there are some video guides available on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=install%20mysql%20on%20linux&oq=install%20mysql%20on%20linux&gs_l=youtube.3..0.6658.10483.0.10843.22.13.0.8.8.1.140.846.11j2.13.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.fv0GkcKB9Wk)

Answer (score 3):

sqlite cannot be used over the network, with login credentials, in the same way you would connect to MySQL or PostgreSQL;  the correct connection string to pass to `create_engine` is just

```
 engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/nwtopology.db')
```

Comment: what should I do to create a database over the network with login credentials?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#connect-strings), you can use this notation:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///\\\\192.168.129.139\\tmp\\nwtopology.db',echo=False)
```

Still do not know how to pass the network credentials, but at least you can access remote files that way. It worked for me.

Comment: Using SQLite over a network share is pretty much discouraged, see "when another RDBMS may work better": https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html